# onActivityResult() is not getting called after initiate the QR code scan from a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, zxing, android-fragmentactivity

I've implemented the zxing-android-embedded library in my android project and trying to get the QR code scan result but onActivityResult() is not being called. My fragment initiates the scan with the intent sent for the camera to scan a QR code.  The camera loads fine, scans a QR code, and returns. The onActivityResult however is never hit. I've set breakpoints, but nothing is triggered.
I used the code as shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)
Here is my code to initiate scan:

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    integrator.initiateScan();
```

Code for getting the scan result:

```
    // Get the results:
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
      if(result.getContents() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       } else {
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           }
       }
```

Why it's not being triggered?

Comment: That's because `onActivityResult` from you activity is called. Use `IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this)` instead of `new IntentIntegrator(getActivity())`, where `this` is your current fragment

Comment: Actually, integrator.initiateScan(); is being called from an onclick(View view) i.e on a button click method so if I use IntentIntegrator(this) gives the context error.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#usage-with-intentintegrator), if you want to have your `onActivityResult()` in your Fragment, you need to use `IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this)`, not `new IntentIntegrator(getActivity())`.

Comment: I already tried both the method but it's giving the Context error as I am calling the IntentIntegrator from inside of the onClick method. The problem is how to get the context of the current fragment and I am using a tabhost to call two different fragments.

Comment: If you are within an `onClick` method, then you need to use `YourFragmentClass.this` with whatever the name of your Fragment's class is.

Answer (score 0):

`IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity())` will send the results to your Activity's `onActivityResult()` method. You should use `IntentIntegrator.forFragment()` or `IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment()` instead.

Comment: I've already tried these methods but I got an error in the context like if I use IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this) it gives the error that I am providing onClickListener instead of fragment because I am calling IntentIntegrator on a button click. I am using tabhost activity so I need to get the context of the fragment to pass it to the IntentIntegrator but don't know how to get the context of the selected fragment.